# 18.04 server - unable to locate package redis-server

Tags: apt, server, package-management, software-installation, redis

I installed a fresh install of 18.04 server. The package `redis-server` does not seem to be installable. I'm not sure why:

```
$ sudo apt install redis-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package redis-server
```

the package doesnt appear to exist:

```
$ sudo apt-cache search redis
miscfiles - Dictionaries and other interesting files
python-redis - Persistent key-value database with network interface (Python library)
resource-agents - Cluster Resource Agents
```

I have run `apt update`. I'm guessing its missing a repository of packages, but since this is a fresh install, I'm not sure why it would be missing one, or how to fix it.

```
root@:/etc/newrelic# sudo apt-get install nri-redis 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package nri-redis
```

Comment: You probably have "universe" disabled. https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/redis-server

Comment: that was it - I'm not sure why it would have been disabled?!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a commenter noted, the `universe` package was not enabled. Enabling with add-apt-repository did the trick:

`sudo add-apt-repository universe`

Comment: I had to run:`sudo apt-get update` first

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue on "Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on Windows 10" and accepted answer doesn't work for me but [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/227788/929233) answer worked. It might help someone else.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

Comment: The question is not about Ubuntu on Windows.

Comment: But I had the same issue. It's eventually Ubuntu. I regret mentioning Windows 10. You are so kind, thank you

Comment: @fkraiem Ubuntu WSL and Ubuntu OS uses same repositories for packages.